# Dirichlet process mixture model with Bayesian hierarchical clustering

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, clustering, mixture-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

I am doing Bayesian hierarchical clustering. From my understanding, there are three basic points for this algorithm.

1. Use marginal likelihoods to decide which clusters to merge
2. Asks what the probability is that all the data in a potential merge were generated   from the same mixture component. Compare to exponentially many hypotheses at lower levels of the tree
3. Generative model used is a Dirichlet Process Mixture Model (DPM)

The first two points are easy to understand, but why the generative model is DPM? Are there specific characteristics of DPM make it quite fit for this purpose?  Are there any other options?

Comment: Dirichlet mixture models don't generate a hierarchical structure, so without spelling out what the algorithm you are referring to is (e.g. by providing a reference) I can't really help. Alternatives which genuinely *do* put a prior on hierarchical structures include (a) Dirichlet diffusion trees and (b) Coalescent based models such as Kingman's Coalescent. These models are *very hard to fit* (this is an area of current research) but are relatively intuitive.